# Why moment.js producing Invalid Date for certain dates only?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Something strange with this function that I cannot figure out what's causing is. There are number of days that users can select from the dropdown. 
The days are : `[3, 7, 14, 21, 28, 30, 60, 90, 180, 365]`

So, when user selects `3`, the moment.js converts it to appropriate ISO date. However, if the user selects 7, 14, or 21, it generates "Invalid Date" but it works for everything else. What's going on?

```
vm.getSelectedDate = function (days) {
            console.log(days);
            if (vm.selectedReminderDay) {

                vm.selectedReminderDate = new Date(vm.today);
                console.log(vm.selectedReminderDate);

                vm.selectedReminderDate.setDate(vm.today.getDate() + days);
                console.log(vm.selectedReminderDate);

                var m = moment(vm.selectedReminderDate, "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A");
                console.log(m);
                vm.utcReminderDate = m.toISOString();
                console.log(vm.utcReminderDate);
                return "in " + vm.selectedReminderDay + " days";
            }
            else {
                return "When?"
            }
        }
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using moment anywhere, but if you were, you could do `addDays` instead of the (going to break) `getDate + x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.getDate()` gets the current day of the month, which will cause unexpected beahvior when it goes out of range (typically when it goes over ~30). What you could use is `Date.getTime()`:

```
vm.selectedReminderDate.setTime(vm.today.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
```

The multiplication is simply to convert the days into milliseconds which `setTime` expects.

---

**But** a better way to do this would be to manipulate the date using momentjs alone, like this:

```
vm.getSelectedDate = function (days) {
    if (vm.selectedReminderDay) {
        var newdate = moment(vm.today).add(days, 'days');
        vm.utcReminderDate = newdate.toISOString();
        return "in " + vm.selectedReminderDay + " days";
    }
    else return "When?";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions for better use of momentjs are valid in other answers.

The actual reason why 7, 14 and 21 seem to be the only numbers that misbehave is the format you're attempting to use for parsing. Moment appears to turn your Date object into a string for parsing and the "MM" part for months matches the day part in the converted string. Hence any date where the day of the month isn't in the range 1-12 fails to work. If you run the same code on another day you will find other magic numbers.

I don't quite track down how MM gets matched with the date part and it might be different in your locale than mine, but I believe it's the gist of it.

Comment: If passed a Date object, Moment will not use the format string to parse; it's just superfluous. See [the source code](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/create/from-anything.js#L66)

Comment: I refused to believe it and went through the code in more depth. It is in fact here: https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.10.6/moment.js#L1335 that the input is taken into account before isDate check is made, causing the input to be converted to string before it ever gets to the function you linked to. (Note: it's for a bit older version that I happened to have installed, didn't look if it's changed since then)

Comment: I wonder why the answer is downvoted and the misinformed comment above upvoted..?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  DonSteep is quite right, even with 2.13. If a format is passed, the date is interpreted as a string. I'm trying to decide whether this is a bug. At some level, ignoring makes sense, but if you're expecting a string and you get a date object, maybe it should attempt to parse a string.

Comment: My bad. You are correct.  Unfortunately S.O. won't let me change my vote until there's some edit made.  If you would be so kind to add an example of the failure to the post I will upvote.  Thanks.

Comment: Bug 3228 in moment.

Comment: I agree. It appears as though, against all common sense, if you pass in a format with a date it parses the toString() value of the date with the specified format. Nonetheless, I believe handling the dates as moments from the outset as in @SeinopSys' answer is the better path.

Comment: No worries. I agree using momentjs all the way is the better option. Here's just the additional explanation for the behavior witnessed.